# Use a value from a field to control the visibility of a field another layer

Tags: qgis, layers, tab, visibility

I have in my project two layers, one vectorial "Enrutamiento" and another non-vectorial "Fusiones",Through the QGIS documentation I managed to establish a relation between these two layers using the uuid identifier and additionally perform a union between these two layers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Given the particularities of my project, I require that depending on the value selected in the "Tipo_Actividad" field of the "Enrutamiento" vector layer, which is a text type and controlled by value map.

[image]

I want to use this value to control the visibility of other fields in the non-vector layer "Fusiones", I have tried to use the field that appears due to the union to control the desired visibility through an expression (Enrutamiento_Tipo_Actividad).

However, apparently it is not possible directly.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, don't understand the question: what is a "tab" in a layer? Can you add a screenshot (edit your initial question and paste the image).

Comment: I think maybe it would help to detail the steps you took in a bullet list. Trying to follow your workflow from the screenshots (especially for non-Spanish speakers) is quite difficult. Don't forget to include the expression you tried too.